# Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Ruby, and I'm getting the following error when I try to execute my script

Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515

I got some posts related to the same error but all of them are for Linux or Mac. I'm using Windows.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: This is the code I'm using it's a very basic one:

`require 'selenium-webdriver

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome

driver.get "http://www.google.com"`

Comment: What is on that port? Is it running? Do you have a firewall blocking the port? Selinux? Try connecting with netcat.